# How to use lightning:inputField in a list view component for mass edit?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I got lightning:inputField and lightning:outputField to work within the context of a detail view by utilizing [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) (by passing in recordId and objectApiName), but is it possible to leverage this new API v42 feature within an aura:iteration so the data could be mass updated? Something like so:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-max-medium-table_stacked slds-table_striped slds-table_col-bordered slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal slds-table--header-fixed" aura:id="main">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="slds-cell-wrap">Name</th>
            <th class="slds-cell-wrap">My Date</th>
            <th class="slds-cell-wrap">My Picklist</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfRecords}" var="r" indexVar="s">
            <tr>
                <td ><lightning:outputField fieldName="Name"/></th>
                <td ><lightning:inputField fieldName="My_Date__c" /></th>
                <td ><lightning:inputField fieldName="My_Picklist__c" /></th>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

How can I pass the objectAPIName for the entire table? Even if not, lightning:inputField and lightning:outputField don't seem to support an objectAPIName attribute.

I am currently handling all picklists, dates, lookups, inputs etc in a mass-editable list view with custom components which seems like an overkill.